# How to play a video randomly without pressing the play button

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm new in iPhone Application Development, and now i faced a problem, can any one tell me how can i play a video randomly without pressing the play button. The video should start automatically while the application launch and play randomly without stopping. I don't have any idea how to do this. I don't have any code also. Please help me any one...

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement it like this:

1. You need a movie player configured with e.g. a file url and add it to your view

   ```
   NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:movieName withExtension:@"mov"];
   moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
   moviePlayer.view.frame = // set the frame
   [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
   ```
2. Start the movie player

   ```
   [moviePlayer play];
   ```
3. Listen to the notification

   ```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleMoviePlayerStatChange:)                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:moviePlayer];
   ```
4. Start the video again

   ```
   - (void)handleMoviePlayerStatChange:(NSNotification *)note {
       NSLog(@"mp playback state %i", moviePlayer.playbackState);
       if (moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) {        
           [moviePlayer play];
       }
   }
   ```

To hide the video controls set the controlStyle property of the movie player instance:

```
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

Comment: Thanks M_G, its working nicely, but can you tell me how can I hide the player, only video will run, no player will show.